# nodejs async.parallel recursion

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

I am test async.parallel behaviour with nodejs.

```js
var async = require("async");

function makeSleepFunction(i) {
 return function(callback) {
   setTimeout(function() {
     console.log('   + sleep '+i);
     callback(null, i);
   }, i);
 }
}

function parallel(i, callback) {
 // console.log('----parallel '+i+'-----')
 return async.parallel([makeSleepFunction(i), makeSleepFunction(i+10)], callback);
}

// Expected result OK: 100 before 10
parallel(100, function(err, results) {
 console.log('async.parallel 1 done: '+results.toString());
 parallel(10, function(err, results) {
  console.log('async.parallel 2 done: '+results.toString());
 });
});

// Expected result KO: 100 after 10
setTimeout(function() { // Wait the 1st test is finished
 console.log('\n\n***** The followig test des not give the expected result:')
 parallel(100,
  parallel(10, function(err, results) {
   console.log('async.parallel 2 done: '+results.toString());
  })
 );
}, 300);
```

Can somebody explain with the second test does not give the expected result?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The async parallel waits for every task done. Your tasks are timed i and i+10. The first call the parallel waits for the longest sleep which is 110 ms.
The second call for same reason waits for 20 ms.
Your code waits minimum 110 + 20 = 130 ms before writes a message: "async.parallel 2 done"

In the second test you not pass a callback, but you call imediately a new parallel function.
try this way:

```
setTimeout(function() { // Wait the 1st test is finished
    console.log('\n\n***** The followig test des not give the expected result:')
    parallel(100,function(){ //not call, but only declare a function
        parallel(10, function(err, results) {
            console.log('async.parallel 2 done: '+results.toString());
        })
    });
}, 300);
```

or you can use bind, of course

Comment: In the 1st test ('expeted result OK'), the 100ms task runs before the 10 ms taks. That is what I expected. But in the 2nd test ('setTimeout...'), The 100ms task is runned AFTER the 10ms task.  Can you tell me why ? here is the log :   + sleep 100
   + sleep 110
async.parallel 1 done: 100,110
   + sleep 10
   + sleep 20
async.parallel 2 done: 10,20

***** The followig test des not give the expected result:
   + sleep 10
   + sleep 20
async.parallel 2 done: 10,20
   + sleep 100
   + sleep 110
[Finished in 0.46s]

Comment: I see, I modified my answer. The problem is you call imediately the parallel(10... function, and not pass the function for first parallel second parameter